# Is building regulations approval needed for replacing gas fire with log burner

Tags: gas, building-regulations, uk

Currently selling my house and the buyer has come back demanding building regulations approval for some work we did replacing a gas fire with a log burner built into an existing chimney.

We did the work about 5 years ago and didn't get any approval.

Is approval required in this case? I looked at the [guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/building-regulations-approval/when-you-need-approval) but am unclear of how this situation fits in.

Comment: Who did the work? If yourselves, then you should have almost certainly sought advice from Building Control. What work did you do, exactly - did you install a liner/flue/etc?

Comment: Have you contacted your local government? They should surely know whether or not approval is required.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is building regulations approval needed for replacing gas fire ... ?**

Permanently removing a gas fire involves capping off or removing the gas pipework and testing it to ensure it is safe.

> 80 Gas work should only be undertaken:
>   (a) by a person who has successfully completed an industry-recognised
>   training course followed by assessment of competence. Training that
>   leads to assessment of competence in safe gas work should be
>   recognised by the industry’s standards setting body; or
>   (b) in the case of a currently or previously registered person, where they
>   have proved competence through a certification scheme; or
>   (c) for those working at premises that fall outside the scope of the
>   Regulations (see regulation 2(4) and associated guidance), by a person
>   who has successfully completed an appropriate full training course
>   followed by assessment of competence.

[Gas Safety (Installation and Use) Regulations 1998 Approved Code of Practice and guidance](http://www.hse.gov.uk/pubns/books/l56.htm)

Unless you are a landlord, there is no legal requirement for a certificate for the gas installation.

My guess is that the buyer wants evidence from a qualified engineer that any remaining gas pipes and equipment are safe and that the chimney flue was properly adapted for the change in use.

Whether you pay someone qualified to inspect and report on the work depends on how much you want to appease this particular potential buyer. I guess it is something that is likely to come up again though.